# Show only changed lines with diff, not newly added lines

Tags: linux, diff

I'm curious if there is a way to get only changed lines with diff, not the newly added lines?

I mean, let's say I have two files file1 and file2.

file1 is:

```
abc=123
def=234
klm=10.10
xyz=6666
```

file2 is:

```
abc+=123
def=234
klm=10.101
xyz=666
stackoverflow=1000
superuser=2000
wtf=911
```

what I want is giving a command like `diff <parameters> file1 file2` and getting an output like

```
- abc=123
+ abc+=123
- klm=10.10
+ klm=10.101
- xyz=6666
+ xyz=666
```

Such output is welcomed too:

```
- abc=123
+ abc+=123
  def=234
- klm=10.10
+ klm=10.101
- xyz=6666
+ xyz=666
```

I don't want the

```
stackoverflow=1000
superuser=2000
wtf=911
```

lines in the output.

Is there a way to get this functionality with the parameters of diff in Linux?

Comment: Ping again? nobody knows whether there is a diff command alternative to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($fname1, $fname2) = ($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1]);

my %conf;
open (my $input1, "<", "$fname1") or die("open $fname1: $!");
while (<$input1>) { 
  chomp; 
  my @v = split(/\+?=/);
  $conf{$v[0]}=$_; 
}
close $input1;

open (my $input2, "<", "$fname2") or die("open $fname2: $!");
while (<$input2>) {
  chomp;
  my @v = split(/\+?=/);
  if (defined ($conf{$v[0]}) && $_ ne $conf{$v[0]}) {
    print "- $conf{$v[0]}\n";
    print "+ $_\n";
  }
}
close $input2;
```

### Output

```
- abc=123
+ abc+=123
- klm=10.10
+ klm=10.101
- xyz=6666
+ xyz=666
```

Comment: Thanks for the script! If I change the input1 and input2 in the quotation marks with the filenames, It works. I'm not that much into perl, how can I change the script as getting the filenames as parameters to the script?

Comment: Another thing, I'm actually curious about the "diff" way of doing this functionality. How can I do this, using the diff command? If there is not a way to achieve my goal using diff program, I'll select the suitable answer as the best answer.

Comment: updated the answer to get filenames from arguments. I don't think `diff` can tell you which lines are updated

Comment: Thank you so much @perreal. In case nobody comes with a "diff" based answer, I'll select yours as "the answer".

Answer (score 1):

Try diff -U0, it should give you only the changed lines without further context.

Comment: `-U0` helps too, but I only want to see the changed lines, not the *added* lines line `stackoverflow=1000
superuser=2000
wtf=911`